# How can I jump to the most recent change of a saved page?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, saves

The previous *bookmark* system allowed me to click on the date of the most recent change, which would then take my directly to the question/answer that got changed. The recent *saves* change does not display the date of the most recent change, it displays the creation date of the question. Nor is the date clickable.

[image: screenshot bookmarks]

How can I see when the last change was made? And more importantly: **How can I jump directly to the most recent changed question/answer?**

Comment: Its sorted by activity so the top one should be the most recent changed one. But yeah the omission of the last modified date is a bit of an oversight IMO. Who cares when the post was created in this specific view.

Comment: What should the view be? *"[Interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting)"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Previously the date shown, was the date of the most recent change. You could then click on that date to directly jump to the most recent changed question/answer. This was in my opinion the correct view. I don't actually care about the specifics of the UI though. If the ability to "jump to most recent change" was clickable under `⋮` it would be fine by me, but the feature seems to be completely removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When viewing the full question, you'll see something along the lines of "Modified today" near the top, and the date part of that is a link to the most recent activity. (This has nothing to do with saves — you can always do this.)

[image: modified today under the question title]

Comment: While true, viewing bookmarks before used to have a direct link to the last modification. The same can be found on pages like the front page. It seems idiomatic on the site that pages that show activity on posts also provide easy access to what that activity was - at a glance (modified, answered, etc) as well as how to get more information (click to go there). You might choose to follow some activity and not other, e.g., answers not modifications.

Comment: This does solve my issue. I used to jump to the latest edit via the bookmark and didn't know you could also jump via the top of the question. It's sad that the old functionality is removed and that I have to do an additional click. But hey, at least I know where to find it again.